# PowerShell Search for Specific files and delete them

Tags: windows, powershell, search, scripting, delete-file

I am learning PS and Couldn't figure this out:

```
$fileName = @("file1.url","file2.url","file3.url")
foreach ($a in $fileName) {
Get-ChildItem -Path \\mySharePath\* -include $fileName -Recurse
} | Remove-Item -Force
```

The purpose is to seach in $filename for each file name and once it's found, delete that file.

Comment: Running `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter Include` tells me that it accepts an array of strings, so you can skip the whole `ForEach` loop and just do `Get-ChildItem \\mySharePath\* -include $filename -recurse|remove-item -force`. Also, you're using `ForEach` wrong. To use it as you are trying to you would do `-include $a` inside the loop.

Comment: You are correct, but testing `Get-ChildItem \\mySharePath\* -include $filename -recurse` will only return my first filename which is file1.url

Comment: `$fileName = @("file1.url","file2.url","file3.url"); Get-ChildItem \\mySharePath\* -include $fileName -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force` worked fine when I tested it, it deleted all 3 files.

Comment: could it be because of my actual file names? These is space in them. so they are like "file number one.url"
when I create the array, i used double quotes to specify the file names; something like this:
`$fileName = @("file number one.url","file number two.url")`

Still didn't work for me... :|

Comment: It really shouldn't. Admittedly, I ran it against files on my C: drive, but I was able to recursively search a folder and find 3 files with spaces in the name using the `-Include` parameter. I don't think it being a network share should impede that.

Comment: I tried it on the C: drive and it works but on the share it doesn't!! can't wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing from the comments.  I see you got it to work from your local machine but trying to do it to a share.  If that sharepath is the server without the actual path to the share folder, it will not work.  You cannot browser a server like that for its shares.  You can use WMI or the new server modules commandlets to get share names from the server but you have to target the share directly to browse it, and interact with it.

For example, try to just gci that "\mysharepath*" server without the include with recurse and you will get nothing back.  Share path should be:

\FileServer\sharedfolder

Recurse that with the correct server name and shared folder and you will get the results you are seeking if the files are in the shared folder.